# Keeping website up to date with fossil scm / shared hosting

Tags: version-control, fossil

For my latest website project I have used fossil for the first time, and it worked well. What I did so far is develop on my PC, and push to chiselapp. So I could now work on the site with a team using the chiselapp repository as a common base. Very nice.

Meanwhile I have uploaded the site and it is running. I want to continue making changes on the PC, then upload the changes. I have done this manually so far, keeping track of changed files, then ftp'ed them to the live site.

Of course I'd like to use fossil to track changes and keep the site up to date. What is the best way to do that? Pushing files like I'm doing to chiselapp seems fine, but I don't know how to do that with another server. It is shared hosting, no root access, no command line.

Answer (score 2):

You said your site is "shared hosting, no root access, no command line."  Is it safe to assume you can use CGI?

If so, see "[How to Configure a Fossil Server: Fossil as CGI](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/server.wiki#cgi)"  :

"A Fossil server can also be run from an ordinary web server as a CGI program. This feature allows Fossil to be seamlessly integrated into a larger website. CGI is how the self-hosting fossil repositories are implemented.

To run Fossil as CGI, create a CGI script (here called "repo") in the CGI directory of your web server and having content like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/fossil
repository: /home/fossil/repo.fossil
```

..."

Answer (score 0):

You may create repository at chiselapp, then clone it to your PC. Setup it as auto-sync(the default mode). That's all.

If you want to keep branches on the chiselapp, maybe you could clone with --private option.

Maybe you could set a cron table on web server. Do fossil update to production version per hour.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. The point is really how to keep a production site up to date, not the version on my PC or on chiselapp.
So what I believe what I need to do is to keep my local version up to date and then upload changes to the production server from time to time. But then I still need to keep track of changed files myself. Or upload everything each time. Or use the synch feature of WinSCP. So there are various ways. But I'm still wondering which would be the best.

Comment: Actually, meanwhile I switched to Subversion. Mostly because Dreamweaver supports it directly, supposedly. Then I found that DW does not *really* support it ... alas.